# has_one association to match 2 foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. I have a table given by supplier, which I can't alter. The `State` has 2 foreign keys. Below is the simplified code:

```
# shops.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "shop_id"
  has_one :state, foreign_key: "shop_id"
end

# states.rb
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = ["shop_id", "country_id"] # when there are multiple parent keys
  belongs_to :shops, foreign_key: "shop_id"  
end

# shop record
shop_id   country_id
====================
1             3

# state records
shop_id   country_id
=====================
1             4
1             6
1             3
1             9
```

You will notice I will only have one `shop` record with `shop_id = 1`, but the `state` would have multiple associated records. How can I be sure that when I run the following, I get the correct record returned?

```
a = Shop.find(1)
a.state # => #<State shop_id: 1, country_id: 3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary key for your state table is composite.  You'll need to specify the country_id when retrieving the correct state record.

```
 a = Shop.find(1)
 a.states.where(:country_id => a.country_id)
```

Comment: But it's `has_one`, must I use `states` or change to `has_many`?

Comment: you'll have to change it to `has_many`, looking at your state table, you clearly have multiple state records for a shop.